# button alpha not restored after animation

Tags: android, button, alpha, textcolor

I am wondering why in the code below my button giftFinal does not get his alpha back. After execution the button text is not visible. Not even the text color or backgroundcolor are set:

```
final float alpha=giftFinal.getAlpha();
            Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
            fadeOut.setStartOffset(30000);
            fadeOut.setDuration(2000);
            fadeOut.setFillAfter(true);
            fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    if(help!=null) {
                        //palce old help text back again
                            giftFinal.setText(help);
                            giftFinal.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            giftFinal.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            giftFinal.setAlpha(alpha);
                            giftFinal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
            });
            giftFinal.startAnimation(fadeOut);
```

Comment: Does `help` have a not null value assigned? It's not in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have set *setFillAfter* as *true*. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29), *"If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished. Defaults to false if not set."* So remove `fadeOut.setFillAfter(true)` or change it to `fadeOut.setFillAfter(false)`.